# Invoking flyway via spring's depends-on attribute causes infinite loop

Tags: java, spring, flyway

I'm using `flyway` via `spring`. In my xml context file I have some bean definitions as follows:

```
<bean id="baseVersion" class="org.flywaydb.core.api.MigrationVersion">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="${flyway.baseVersion}"/>
</bean>  
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="${database.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${database.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${database.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>  
</bean>
<bean id="flyway" class="org.flywaydb.core.Flyway" init-method="migrate" >
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
            <property name="baselineVersion" ref="baseVersion"/>
            <property name="baselineOnMigrate" value="${flyway.baselineOnMigrate}"/>
            <property name="validateOnMigrate" value="${flyway.validateOnMigrate}"/>
            <property name="ignoreFutureMigrations" value="${flyway.ignoreFutureMigrations}"/>
            <property name="ignoreMissingMigrations" value="${flyway.ignoreMissingMigrations}"/>
            <property name="outOfOrder" value="${flyway.outOfOrder}"/>
            <property name="targetAsString" value="${flyway.targetVersion}"/>
</bean>
<!-- *************************************************************** -->
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean" depends-on="flyway">
        <property name="annotatedClasses" >
            <list>
                 <value>foo.bar.Entity1</value>
                 ...
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                  <value>/hbms/Table1.hbm.xml</value>
                  ....
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${database.dialect}</prop>
                ...
            </props>
        </property>
</bean>
```

The problem is that when flyway fails on migration, spring swallows its exception and retries to invoke it again and again ... and falls on an infinite loop!

```
2017-11-21 10:07:35,280 [main] INFO  o.f.c.i.dbsupport.DbSupportFactory  - Database: jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.99.100:1521:orcl (Oracle 11.2)
2017-11-21 10:07:37,564 [main] INFO  o.f.c.i.dbsupport.DbSupportFactory  - Database: jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.99.100:1521:orcl (Oracle 11.2)
2017-11-21 10:07:38,884 [main] INFO  o.f.c.i.dbsupport.DbSupportFactory  - Database: jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.99.100:1521:orcl (Oracle 11.2)
2017-11-21 10:07:39,565 [main] INFO  o.f.c.i.dbsupport.DbSupportFactory  - Database: jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.99.100:1521:orcl (Oracle 11.2)
2017-11-21 10:07:40,214 [main] INFO  o.f.c.i.dbsupport.DbSupportFactory  - Database: jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.99.100:1521:orcl (Oracle 11.2)
...
```

One consequence of this problem is that Oracle locks the user when password is wrong, because the `FAILED_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS` exceeds from `LIMIT` value when it's not `UNLIMITED`!

I've traced the code of spring ... the exception is catched at line 1760 of `AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory` class and goes forward ... and finally somehow suppressed despite the `recordSuppressedExceptions` is `false` in `DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry` class!

The `spring-beans` version is `4.3.11` and the version of `flyway` is `4.2.0`.
Any solution or workaround?

p.s. Spring prints the flyway's exception just when I increase the level of log to `TRACE`.

---

UPDATE
Flyway's properties:

```
#database migration config
flyway.baseVersion=1.0
flyway.baselineOnMigrate=true
flyway.validateOnMigrate=true
flyway.locationsToScan=db/migration
flyway.ignoreFutureMigrations=true
flyway.ignoreMissingMigrations=false
flyway.outOfOrder=false
#taget migration version, i.e. the version up to which the migration is done.
#migrations with a higher version number will be ignored. Default=BigInteger.valueOf(-1)
flyway.targetVersion=9223372036854775807
```

Comment: What's the exception when you turn on your logging?

Comment: @SMA The flyway's exception is `Validate failed: Migration checksum mismatch for migration 3.4
-> Applied to database : -728493870
-> Resolved locally    : 1446984848`. But the exception of spring is `2017-11-21 11:12:07,099 [main] TRACE o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory  - Ignoring constructor [public org.jasypt.spring31.properties.EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer(org.jasypt.util.text.TextEncryptor)] of bean 'org.jasypt.spring31.properties.EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer#1': org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with ... `

Comment: @SMA The exceptions are not important, I can resolve them. What I need is the spring doesn't falls on an infinite loop. It must print the exception and terminate the application statrtup.

Comment: Which is what it does (at least here) so I suspect you have some configuration of flyway that tells flyway to ignore the exceptions... What are your `flyway.*` properties?

Comment: @SMA I'm sure that the `ignoreFutureMigrations` property is OK, but know suspect to `ignoreMissingMigrations`. Let me reread its javadoc again ...

Comment: @M.Deinum Its javadoc says: `Ignore missing migrations when reading the metadata table. These are migrations that were performed by an older deployment of the application that are no longer available in this version. ...` so it's also OK. Moreover I set it to its default value, i.e. `false`. I'm sure that it's spring that retries, because when I run flyway with it's maven goal `mvn flyway:migrate` it prints the exception and is terminated.

Comment: You have more flyway properties. Add them to your question.

Comment: @M.Deinum It's done.

Comment: @faghani Did you manage to resolve this? I'm also facing this issue with flyway 4.2.0 and spring boot 1.5.7